# Following the most recent update, I've lost twin monitor functionality

Tags: display, screen, radeon

With Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, a few hours ago I had an update of the system,. Since then my dual monitor has lost any setup. The system does not even see or recognize the monitors and it displays the same screen for both monitors.

With `apt-get update` I get a signature error

```
Error:9 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian ubuntu InRelease              
 : EXPKEYSIG 9386B48A1A693C5C James Adrian Edwards (ROCm Release Manager) <JamesAdrian.Edwards@amd.com>
```

Any idea of what has happened and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Update the signature and update again probably the driver is not updated yet

```
wget -q -O - https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/rocm.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade 

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall      // Optional * Try only if update does not fix the issue
```

Comment: Hello Utkarsh Chandra Srivastava,
thank you for your help. It kind of solved, but the last command did not work at all, it gave an error similar to " operation ubunti-drivers not valid.
But all seems now to work, hope it will keep that way...

Comment: I am sorry I made a typo in the last command , anyways it is  not required  if the update already fixes the drivers. Glad to be of help. Updated the answer.

Comment: meanwhile the link http://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/debian/rocm.gpg.key is dead